# Calculating the mean trajectory from many trajectories in numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have many trajectory files, each of them is having 3 columns denoting position `x`, `y` and `z`. I want to calculate the mean position, which is basically defined as following - for a given row, calculate the mean of `x` from all trajectories. Similarly for `y` and `z` dimension also.

So, I am iterating over each of these array and storing all `x` in one list and similarly for  `y` and `z`. Later I am calculating the mean. See below the sample code-

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

file_list = ['test1_1', 'test2_4', 'test3_1', 'test4_3', 'test1_3']
position_data_list = []
for f in file_list:
    position_data = pd.read_csv(f) 
    position_data_list.append(position_data.values)

position_x_list = []
position_y_list = []
position_z_list = []
for position_data in position_data_list:
    px = _position_data[:, 0]
    py = _position_data[:, 1]
    pz = _position_data[:, 2]
    position_x_list.append(px)
    position_y_list.append(py)
    position_z_list.append(pz)

position_x_list = np.array(position_x_list).T
position_y_list = np.array(position_y_list).T
position_z_list = np.array(position_z_list).T

position_x_mean = np.mean(position_x_list, axis=1)
position_y_mean = np.mean(position_y_list, axis=1)
position_z_mean = np.mean(position_z_list, axis=1)
```

Is there any better way to do the same?

Let me explain the above code. Suppose `files` are `file_1`, `file_2` and `file_3`. Each file has `x`, `y`, and `z` column, where each row is time stamp say `t1`, `t2`, `t3`, `t4` and `t5`. The mean trajectory should contain all the rows from `t1` to `t5`, where `x1` is mean of `x` from file `file_1`, `file_2` and `file_3` of row `t1`. and so on...

Comment: @Divakar: what do you mean? as said earlier, trajectory file `test1_1` is a csv having 3 columns, x,y and z.

Comment: But I don't know what those CSV files have. So, some minimal representative data that you are getting into `position_data_list` might help us to help you. Like what are their shapes/sizes, etc.

Comment: if you do not actually need the individual `x`, `y` and `z` you can just use them to calculate the mean and store the result only. For example, instead of appending the matrices just add them on the spot and at the end divide by the number of files. Should be 3-4 lines of code in total

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually pandas is very powerful and can do much more than just reading data. You've already read the data into a pandas dataframe, then you can just concatenate your dataframes and calculate the mean of each column with pandas. If you are trying to calculate the mean for each time stamp, you can try the groupby funciton. Assuming the column name for your time stamp is "ts", then try the following:

```
import pandas as pd
file_list = ['test1_1', 'test2_4', 'test3_1', 'test4_3', 'test1_3']
df = pd.DataFrame()             # Create an empty dataframe
for file in file_list:
    df2 = pd.read_csv(file)     # Read data and store the results in df2
    df = pd.concat([df, df2])   # Concatenate your dataframes and store the results in df
print(df.groupby('ts').mean())  # Assuming 'ts' is the column of time stamp, print the results
```

Input:

```
file1: 

ts  x   y   z
t1  1   3   5
t2  2   4   6
t3  3   5   7
t4  4   6   8
t5  5   7   9

file2:

ts  x   y   z
t1  1   4   5
t2  2   6   6
t3  3   8   7
t4  4   10  8
t5  5   12  9
```

output:

```
      x    y    z
ts               
t1  1.0  3.5  5.0
t2  2.0  5.0  6.0
t3  3.0  6.5  7.0
t4  4.0  8.0  8.0
t5  5.0  9.5  9.0
```

Comment: Let me explain you again. Suppose `files` are `file_1`, `file_2` and `file_3`. Each file has `x`, `y`, and `z` column, where each row is time stamp say `t1`, `t2`, `t3`, `t4` and `t5`. The mean trajectory should contain all the rows from `t1` to `t5`, where `x1` is mean of `x` from file `file_1`, `file_2` and `file_3` of row `t1`. and so on...

Comment: So you want to calculate the mean for each time stamp, not for all the time  stamps?

Comment: Yeah. Exactly!!

Comment: Why someone downvoted? I think this is the correct answer!

Answer (score 0):

So you want to average each coordinates over the frames and you can have all your frames as arrays in memory. Then you can have your all trajectory as a single array where one dimension represent the frames, an other one the moving elements (your current lines), and the last dimension represents the axis (your current columns). Assuming your dimensions are in that order, then you want the mean of that array over the first dimension: you can use `my_array.mean(axis=0)`.

I got the same result on a test system with the following code as with your example:

```
file_list = glob('csv_frames/*')

position_data_list = []
for frame in file_list:
    position_data_list.append(numpy.loadtxt(frame, delimiter=','))
# Convert the list of arrays into a 3D array
position_data_list = numpy.asarray(position_data_list)

# Actually calculate the averaged coordinates
position_mean = position_data_list.mean(axis=0)

# If realy you need each axis on its own array
position_x_mean = position_mean[:, 0]
position_y_mean = position_mean[:, 1]
position_z_mean = position_mean[:, 2]
```

In my example, I use `numpy.loadtxt` to read the CSV file. Depending on your files you may have to tweak the arguments. You can also use pandas to read the file and extract an array from your DataFrame using the [`as_matrix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.as_matrix.html) method.

I built my test frames from a molecular dynamics simulation trajectory using [MDAnalysis](http://www.mdanalysis.org/):

```
import numpy
import MDAnalysis as mda
from MDAnalysisTests.datafiles import TPR, XTC

# Read the trajectory
u = mda.Universe(TPR, XTC)
# Write each frame in a separate CSV file
for ts in u.trajectory:
    numpy.savetxt('csv_frames/frame_{}.csv'.format(ts.frame),
                  u.atoms.positions, delimiter=',')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import glob, os


file_list = ['test1_1', 'test2_4', 'test3_1', 'test4_3', 'test1_3']
position_data_list =  pd.DataFrame()
for f in file_list:
    position_data_list =position_data_list.append(pd.read_csv(tfile))

position_data_list.columns=['X','Y','Z']
print position_data_list["Y"].mean()
print position_data_list["X"].mean()
print position_data_list["Z"].mean()
```

input

```
5.742023, 0.193241, 2.874091
8.742023, 0.35, 2.78
23, 0.55, 2.89
7.742023, 0.65, .8274091
```

output

```
0.516666666667
13.1613486667
2.16580303333
```